# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in asp.net web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, webserver, cross-domain

I have 2 Project one is Asp.Net Web Service and second is Asp.Net Web Application, When I am trying to run both project in same solution its run perfectly but when we run project separately (on localhost but with port number, I am getting error).
I am hard trying to solve this but no perfect solution got.

**WebServiceServer:**

```
[WebMethod]
public void CheckUserNameAndGetNew(string UserName)
{
    bool IsUserNameAvailable = true;
    DAL dal = new DAL();

    UserNameCheck objBel = new UserNameCheck();

    //IsUserNameAvailable = dal.CheckUserNameDAL(UserName);

    while(!dal.CheckUserNameDAL(UserName))   // get in if UserName already exist in database
    {
        Random myRandomNum =new Random();
        int myRandomNumber = myRandomNum.Next(1, 100);

        UserName = UserName + myRandomNumber;
        IsUserNameAvailable = false;
    }

    objBel.IsUserNameAvailable = IsUserNameAvailable;
    objBel.UserName = UserName;

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(objBel));
}
```

**WebServer:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:49839/WebService1.asmx/CheckUserNameAndGetNew",
    method: "Post",
    data: { UserName: txtUserName },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        var AvailableMsg = $('#AvailableMsg');
        var Availablelbl = $('#Availablelbl');
        var AvailableUserName = $('#AvailableUserName');
        if (data.IsUserNameAvailable) {
            AvailableMsg.text(txtUserName + ' User Name Available');
            Availablelbl.text('');
            AvailableUserName.text('');
            AvailableMsg.css('color', 'Green');
        }
        else {
            AvailableMsg.text(txtUserName + ' User Name is not Available');
            Availablelbl.text('Available: ');
            AvailableUserName.text(data.UserName).click(function () {
                $('#txtUserName').val($(this).text());
                AvailableMsg.text('');
                Availablelbl.text('');
                AvailableUserName.text('');
            });
            AvailableMsg.css('color', 'red');
            Availablelbl.css('color', 'Gray');
            AvailableUserName.css('color', 'green');
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

**Error at client Side Inspect Console:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:49839/WebService1.asmx/CheckUserNameAndGetNew. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:65360' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also allow web service server to provide data cross domain (means also other's call request-response). So for that you need to flowing settings in **web.config of your Web Service Server**.

```
 <system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```